# spring boot app works running as an executable jar but not as a war deployed on jboss EAP 6

Tags: java, jboss7.x, spring-boot

I am developing a spring-boot application which uses camel and cxf. I also include the spring-boot-starter-actuator. The actuator end points (e.g. /beans, /info, /env) work fine when executing the application as an executable jar or as a war deployed to Tomcat 8. However, when I deploy the same war to JBoss EAP 6 (AS 7) the actuator end points return a http status of 404. I have tried including the following dependencies in my pom.xml as per the documentation without success.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My application class looks like

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

import java.util.Arrays;

@SpringBootApplication 
public class EsbApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EsbApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(EsbApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Any ideas on how I can get the actuator end points working in JBoss EAP

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

It would appear the JBoss EAP 6 servlet mapping works as /* but not with /

To avoid having to add a web.xml, I had to add the following to my SpringBootServletInitializer class

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    registration.addMapping("/*"); // required JBOSS EAP 6 / AS 7
    super.onStartup(container);
}
```

Comment: Maybe just set "server.servletPath=/*"?